# “Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid” appearing when accessing Branch link with app uninstalled

Tags: ios, safari, branch.io

Similar to this question:

["Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" appearing when accessing Branch link with app uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455960/safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-appearing-when-acce)

I am integrating with branch.io.  In both Chrome and Safari, if I open the link that Branch.io created for me and the app is installed, the app opens, which is what is desired.  However, on Safari, if the app is NOT installed  and I click the link, I get an alert message from Safari that says "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" before I am asked if I want to open the app store.

Unlike the question I linked to above (with it's answer from Aaron of branch.io), I have enabled universal links in the Branch dashboard.

What am I missing to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the issue occurs when the application is uninstalled - it has nothing to do with Universal Linking (UL).

The most likely reason for this is that you are testing on the same device re-installing the app many times in a short period of time. This causes Branch's persona to believe that you have the application installed, so it tries to forcefully open the application via the URI scheme, when the UL fails.

The easiest way to check if that is what's causing the issue, is by disabling the **URI Scheme Deep Link Mode** in your [Link Settings](https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings)

This issue would rarely, if ever, happen to regular users of your application.