# How should I configure a valid address for my Expo App? (Configuring an Azure AD Authentication)

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, expo

I am trying to implement a Microsoft Azure AD Login authentication on my Expo app.
All the keys and IDs are set, but once I login with my account using the two factor authentication, Safari is unable to open the redirectUri.

It says: "Safari is unable to open the page because the address is invalid"

My redirectUri is set as `msauth.com.negocie://auth` (being 'com.negocie' the bundleID of my app)

Once I change it to `redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({msauth.com.negocie:://auth})` it crashes the app

How should I authenticate my users?

[Image of the error message saying "Safari is unable to open the page because the address is invalid", how do I configure a valid address?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JVkU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below points:

1. Firstly When you’re certain the web address is spelled correctly, tap  Refresh button in Safari to try loading it again  or you can try again on a new device.
2. When selecting the Public client (mobile & desktop) from dropdown,Register the  correct redirect URLs in your tenant:
3. iOS: msauth.<BUNDLE_ID>://auth.
   ex: msauth.energy.msal.example://auth
4. Android: msauth://com.example/Xo8WBi6jzSxXXXXXXXX

Make sure you add your application's redirect URI scheme to your `Info.plist` file. Redirect URI scheme follows the format `msauth.[app_bundle_id]`. Make sure to substitute [app_bundle_id] with the Bundle Identifier for your application.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>msauth. [app_bundle_id]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Please do **Refer** [vmurin/react-native-azure-auth: React Native library implementing Azure AD OAuth2 API (github.com)](https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth#ios-config) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492442/react-native-ios-safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-af)

- `Configure AppDelegate.m file`
- Register a URL type entry using the value of CFBundleIdentifier as
  the value of   `CFBundleURLSchemes`.

Check for  technical [workarounds.](https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-fix-when-safari-cannot-open-a-page-because-the-address-is-invalid/#:%7E:text=%5BSolution%5D%20Safari%20cannot%20Open%20a%20Page%20because%20the,think%20the%20address%20is%20invalid%20because...%20See%20More.)

- You can clear your Safari cache (Settings > Safari > Clear History
  and Website Data) to remove the error. you can set the URI Scheme
  Deep Link Mode to “Conservative Mode” as said in referred links and
  Configure AppDelegate.m file in ios in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492442/react-native-ios-safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-af)

> Note:The error may occur due to  wrong URL Scheme.Check  on info
> settings in XCode to check the correct scheme.

**References:**

1. Check this > [xamarin-native issues](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/10#issuecomment-477914112)  and [reactjs - React Native
   iOS "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"
   after valid login - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492442/react-native-ios-safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-af) and make changes according to
   react native expo.
2. [AzureAD (MSAL) for iOS and macOS (github.com)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc#adding-msal-to-your-project)